# custom customer attribute - find customers with no entry

Tags: php, magento

I created a custom attribute named invoice_email for the customer entity. What I want to do now is get all customers, where invoice_email is not populated yet. What I tried:

```
Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('invoice_email', array('eq' => ''))
```

That doesn't work. There are over a thousand customers in my database with an empty invoice_email field, so the resulting 0 entries is just wrong. If I try it the other way, like

```
Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('invoice_email', array('neq' => ''))
```

it works just fine and returns 6 entries. When I output the query, it looks like this:

```
SELECT `e`.*, `at_invoice_email`.`value` AS `invoice_email` FROM `customer_entity` AS `e` INNER JOIN `customer_entity_varchar` AS `at_invoice_email` ON (`at_invoice_email`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_invoice_email`.`attribute_id` = '292') WHERE (`e`.`entity_type_id` = '1') AND (at_invoice_email.value = '')
```

So the problem seems to be the INNER JOIN, if I change it to LEFT JOIN and value = '' to value IS NULL it works. Is there a way to handle this problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add this attribute to select and set join type as left

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection');
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('invoice_email', 'left');
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('invoice_email', array('null' => true));
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try :

```
Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('invoice_email',  array('null' => true));
```

Answer (score 0):

turns out there is an option to force a jeft join:

```
->addAttributeToFilter('invoice_email', array('null' => true), 'left')
```

The important part is the last parameter, "left". With that it works!